# Proving that HK is a subgroup when K is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$HK = \{hk: h \in H\text{ and }k \in K\}$

I need to first prove first $e \in HK$. Since $e \in H$ and $e \in K$.

Hence we have $e \cdot e = e \in HK$.

Suppose $hk, h'k' \in HK$.

$hk \cdot (h'k')^{-1} = hkk'^{-1}h'^{-1} = hkh'^{-1}k''^{-1}$

$hkh'^{-1}k''^{-1} = hh'^{-1}k_2k''^{-1} \in HK$.

Hence proved.

Comment: Since $K$ is normal, $HK=\bigcup hK=\bigcup Kh=KH$, and this guarantees that $HK$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Is $H$ a subgroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would present it. You can combine the inverse and closure checks into one check.

Clearly $e\in HK$ as you have said. Now consider $h_1k_1, h_2k_2\in HK$. Then we need to show that $h_1k_1 (h_2k_2)^{-1}\in HK$. This is true because
$$h_1k_1 (h_2k_2)^{-1}= h_1k_1 k_2^{-1}h_2^{-1} = \underbrace{h_1 h_2^{-1}}_{\in H} \underbrace{h_2 k_1 h_2^{-1}}_{\in K} \underbrace{h_2 k_2^{-1} h_2^{-1}}_{\in K}\in HK.$$