# Condition for $HK$ to be a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

For subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$, under what conditions is $HK$ a normal subgroup of $G$?

I know that $H\le N_G(K)$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for $HK$ to be a subgroup of $G$, and that if both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, then $HK$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ as well. But I'm looking for a weaker condition for $HK$ to be normal.

Comment: I doubt you can find an easy answer. For example, in $S_3$, $H=A_3$ and $K$ a subgroup of order $2$ gives you a normal subgroup, even though $K$ is self-normalizing.  Or take $H=S_{n-1}$ as a subgroup of $S_n$, and $K=\langle (1,2,\ldots,n)\rangle$. For $n\gt 3$, neither of them are normal, but $HK=S_n$ is trivially normal in $S_n$. Here $H$ is self-normalizing. So I doubt you will get any easy conditions based on $H$, $K$, $N_G(H)$, and $N_G(K)$, for instance.

Comment: If $H=K$ then you are just asking for a condition for $H$ to be a normal subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, $HK$ need not be a subgroup. In fact, it is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$, see also
here: [$HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK = KH$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681831/hk-is-a-subgroup-of-g-if-and-only-if-hk-kh). If one of the subgroups is normal, this is automatically satisfied and $HK$ is a subgroup - see [Proving that HK is a subgroup when K is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213822/proving-that-hk-is-a-subgroup-when-k-is-normal).

Secondly, it looks like that the only concise condition for $HK$ being a normal subgroup is, that both $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups.